# Package Error At Execution Timing

Tags: ssis, sql-server-2012, content-assist, ssis-2008, msbi

I have 10 package in SQL server integration service. When I was trying to execute them out of them 5 are executed correctly, then 6, 7 are giving error and 8, 9, 10 are executed correctly... So how we can handle it?

Comment: provide integration snippet or error log to find where the error is.

Answer (score 0):

You could write an OnError Event Handler for the package that captures all the error values and writes them to a db error table or flat file.